# Casting lines on terrain

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, physics, vertices

I have a DXF file which is a 2D file (all lines are on one layer), and I have a 3D terrain model.

I'd like to cast these lines on terrain (to keep X,Y axis, and stretch with Z axis automatically). 
I can't find any fast way to do it. I know I can adjust every vertex manually, but It is almost impossible with few thousands hektares.

I attach 2 images to show my problem

View from the top[image: View from the TOP]
View from the side
[image: View from the side]
Can you please help?

Comment: Try the Shrinkwrap modifier with projection mode.

Comment: Thanks! Works almost like I want it ! :) There are few things to adjust, but it is the function I was looking for!